# RushORM store RequestParams

Tags: android, android-sqlite, rushorm

I'm using [rushorm](http://www.rushorm.com/) for sqlite object serializing and storage. It work pretty cool so far. The problem is that I wan't to store following `Request` object:

```
public class Request extends RushObject {

    private String url;
    private RequestParamsStorable params;

    public Request() {}

    public Request(String aUrl, RequestParamsStorable aParams)
    {
        this.url = aUrl;
        this.params = aParams;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return this.url;
    }

    public RequestParams getParams()
    {
        return this.params;
    }

}
```

As you can see I need to store RequestParams object. In order to store it, as I obviously cannot make it to extend `RushObject` I made a subclass and made it to implement Rush as per docs instructions:

```
public class RequestParamsStorable extends RequestParams implements Rush {

    public RequestParamsStorable() {}

    @Override
    public void save() { RushCore.getInstance().save(this); }
    @Override
    public void save(RushCallback callback) { RushCore.getInstance().save(this, callback); }
    @Override
    public void delete() { RushCore.getInstance().delete(this); }
    @Override
    public void delete(RushCallback callback) { RushCore.getInstance().delete(this, callback); }
    @Override
    public String getId() { return RushCore.getInstance().getId(this); }
}
```

It didn't throw any errors and calling `save()` on `Request` object went smoothly. When I ask for stored objects like that:

```
    List<Request> remainingsInDB = new RushSearch().find(Request.class);
```

I indeed receive stored `Request` objects, with proper `url`, however `RequestParamsStorable` is empty(""). I checked and when I save them, they definetely had values, and are not empty.

So the question is where I'm wrong?

Regards,

Comment: Is the RequestParams object your are extending this? https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.java

Comment: Yes it is. I understand the `final` problem and trying to make a workaround with JSONObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent class **RequestParams** contains fields declared as **final**, they will not be restored.

As reference you can see the RushORM source code

**ReflectionClassLoader.java**

```java
    for (Field field : fields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if (!annotationCache.get(clazz).getFieldToIgnore().contains(field.getName())) {
            if (!loadJoinField(object, rushColumns, annotationCache, field, joins, joinTables)) {
                if(rushColumns.supportsField(field)) {
                    String value = values.get(counter);
                    if(value != null && !value.equals("null")) {
                        rushColumns.setField(object, field, value);
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You should either remove **final** modifier of the fields or create wrapper object which will be stored in the db and then restore RequestParams from it

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem indeed is fields declared as `final` in RequestParams. @Stuart Campbell properly noted [RequestParams](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.java) reference. Now what I'm trying as a workaround is to store all properties(except Wrappers) as `JSONObject`, store this `JSONObject` as `String` and then restore state from it. I'm facing some issues with `JsonWritter` and didn't solved my issue yet. Not sure if it is a good idea to post relevant code here, or to post new question though?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.rushorm.com/advanced.html#Customise

You could create a custom column type for RequestParams and do you serialization and deserialization there.